# Heroku won't let anyone sign out of app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am following Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial and just finished the chapter on signing in and out of the app. Everything works perfectly on localhost, but when deployed to heroku it automatically logs you in as example user and the signout button no longer works.

Like I stated before, I can sign out without a problem on localhost. It only seems to be broken on heroku.

I should also add that if I create a new user while logged in as local host, it will infact create a new user and log you in as that new user. You can even log out as the new user. But once you log out as the new user it goes back to being logged in as example user.

if it helps, here is the example app: https://serene-bayou-7583.herokuapp.com/

Anyone know what could be causing this? I don't even know what part of my code I should post to help solve the issue.

Edit: Stack won't let me answer my own question, so here is the fix for anyone else with this problem

Here is the answer to my question for anyone else that has this issue. Essentially it looks like heroku is matching NIL to example user. So we change the code slightly to stop that behavior. The only side effect is not being able to stay logged in as example user, but otherwise it works fine! Change this in your sessions helper:

```
    def current_user
        if cookies[:remember_token].present?
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    end
end
```

Comment: i have no problem to sign up and sign out

Comment: I just manged to fix it, thanks for taking the time to look! if anyone else has this problem, here is the fix in your sessions helper  `def current_user
  if cookies[:remember_token].present?
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
 end
end`

Comment: +1 for the serene-bayou subdomain. Same here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question for anyone else that has this issue. Essentially it looks like heroku is matching NIL to example user. So we change the code slightly to stop that behavior. The only side effect is not being able to stay logged in as example user, but otherwise it works fine! Change this in your sessions helper:

```
    def current_user
    if cookies[:remember_token].present?
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

end